# could not load file or assembly 'microsoft.analysisservices.adomdclient version=10.0.0.0

Tags: visual-studio, sql-server-2012

I have recently  installed instance of SQL Server 2012 and SQL Server 2014,
Visual Studio 2015 and  Window 10.When i am trying to create report in existing project using Report Wizard of VS2015, i am getting the error such as "could not load file or assembly "microsoft.analysisservices.adomdclient version=10.0.0.0",however if i try to create a report in new project using Report Wizard  it is working fine without any issue.Please share with me if you have any solutions for this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [link](https://www.kb.blackbaud.com/articles/Article/57601) helped me to resolve this issue.I had to install SQL Server 2008 R2 feature pack( Microsoft® SQL Server® 2008 R2 ADOMD.NET and Microsoft® Analysis Services OLE DB Provider..etc) despite the fact that i have already installed latest version of SQL Server .

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by  install  Microsoft® SQL Server®  ADOMD.NET   for the needed SQL version  and restart  the server.